# Java process.waitFor(time, unit) does not time out

Tags: java

In my Java 11 (openjdk 11.0.3 2019-04-16 under Debian) program I use ProcessBuilder to launch external commands. The external command can hang so I need it to time out after a given amount of time.

So I use `p.waitFor(time, unit)` which should return

> true if the process has exited and false if the waiting time elapsed before the process has exited.

```
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(externalCommand);

        // Merges the error stream with the standard output stream
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process p = pb.start();

        Date start = new Date();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));

        String tempLine;

        /**
         * We only want the first 10 lines otherwise it will print thousands of
         * useless lines (always the same)
         */
        int nbOfLinesInlogs = 10;

        while ((tempLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // We only report errors to the user
            if (tempLine.toLowerCase().startsWith("error") && nbOfLinesInlogs > 0) {
                Level level = Level.WARNING;


                System.err.println("External command output : " + tempLine);
                // There was an error
                errorDetected = true;

                nbOfLinesInlogs--;
            }

        }


        if (p.waitFor(10l,
                TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)) {

            long elapsedInMillis = new Date().getTime() - start.getTime();
            System.err.println("External process succeeded and took " + elapsedInMillis + " ms");
            // prints Externalprocess succeeded and took 15327 ms
            ...
         }
         else {
            System.err.println("External process timed out");
            // This is never printed!
            throw new InterruptedException(
                    "External process timed out!");
         }
```

However the process never times out and prints that it took 15 s although it should time out after 10 ns (this is just a test to check that the time out works as expected). I also tried µs, ms and s with the same result.

What can I do to make the process return false when it times out ?

Any help appreciated,

Comment: I assume there isn't 15s worth of computing hidden behind the `...` that's between `Date start = new Date();` and `p.waitFor(10l, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)` ?

Comment: @Aaron would it change anything ? The waitFor(...) would see that the time is exceeded and should return false, shouldn't it ?

Comment: Are you handling the input stream and error stream of the `Process` you are creating? In my experience with `ProcessBuilder`, not handling the `Process` streams correctly can cause problematic behaviour. Remember, you need to handle the streams in separate threads - one for input stream and another one for error stream.

Comment: @HelloWorld what Aaron is saying is that if there's something that takes a lot of time before you start waiting, the process could actually have ended already, because those 15s passed between the time you started the process and the time you started waiting.

Comment: Can you also print the time after `...` immediately before you start waiting?

Comment: Which OS (with Version) are you using? Exact Java version? Which jvm vendor? (Azuul, OpenJDK, OraceJDK etc.) Have you tried to use 1 second (instead of nanoseconds), maybe this low resolution is not supported by your system.

Comment: @Thilo : I just did what you suggested and it prints "process succeeded and took 0 ms". So you're all right with your advices. I am handling the input and error streams and this is done before the `p.waitFor(...)`.

Comment: I just ran your code locally. It worked for me, and timed out. (I am running on openjdk8 though)

Comment: @Abra : You are right I am handling them. Please see my edit.

Comment: @bratkartoffel : this is OpenJDK 11.0.3 under Debian Linux.

Comment: @HelloWorld : Can you try a different version of openjdk? It worked for me with openjdk8

Comment: I just had the funniest idea.... is maybe your *system time off*? If you java VM and your system assume different times, the waited period might be miscalculated...

Comment: @TreffnonX what "external command" did you execute? I don't see any explicit command mentioned in the original post. So how can you say that it worked for you?

Comment: @TreffnonX I tried under OpenJDK 1.8.0 with the same results. This is a desktop PC and the system time shows the correct time. Was it what you meant ? This is tesseract-ocr command.

Comment: @HelloWorld I don't see in the code you posted where you are using a separate thread to read the `Process` input stream. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Abra : `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));` but it is not in a separate thread. So it is not what you meant, is it ?

Comment: @HelloWorld, yes it was. Thank you for trying.

Comment: _it is not in a separate thread_ Any reason why not? As I commented earlier, in my experience it **must** be in a separate thread. It's not hard to do and there are many online examples showing how to do it.

Comment: @Abra, The entire read block is debugging only. In my code example, I removed it entirely. The interesting question is why the thread waits on waitFor, despite the timeout being reached.

Comment: @HelloWorld, Please debug through ProcessImpl.class (waitFor(long, TimeUnit)). In openjdk8, it calls `getExitCodeProcess`. Maybe this locks, instead of returning immediately...? As this is a native method, it cannot be debugged itself, but you can observe, if it returns or locks.

Comment: @Abra *Any reason why not?* Because I did not know. I only remember adding this piece of code because the external command was sometimes hanging endlessly. But I think you pointed out the issue (as the other commentors) since removing this piece of code solved the problem. Would you mind pointing me to some resources that explain what the problem is when not running in a separate thread ?

Comment: Because you used a while loop which only returns false, once the input is closed. Since your input only closes when the process terminates, your check (waitFor) happens after the process has ended.

Comment: @TreffnonX now I understand what happens and why Abra advised to run the "debugging" part inside a separate thread. Feel free to post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it (although I wrote a solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your comments. According to the comments above, one solution is to remove the piece of code between the process start and the process wait process (`waitFor(...)`)

```
p = pb.start()
// Everything in-between removed
if(p.waitFor(10l, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {

// Now this code is not processed in case of time out
}
```

The reason is (see @TreffnonX comment)

> Because I used a while loop which only returns false, once the input is closed. Since my input only closes when the process terminates, my check (waitFor) happens after the process has ended.

Another solution could be to launch a separate thread that will run this while loop.

Comment: No it isn't, and it is not 'according to the comments above'. Nobody said that. That can cause the process to block indefinitely trying to write its output, which can cause a spurious timeout when it is working perfectly apart from your neglect of its I/O. You need to consume all the output *and* check your timeout, at the same time.

Comment: @user207421 I don't know what comments you have been reading, but we *did* suggest this. Also, the suggestion of reading the output in a separate thread has been suggested, but the timeout can occure without the output being consumed.

Comment: @TreffnonX I don't see where anybody suggested not reading the process output, but if you did you're wrong, and the timeout can occur *because* of the output not being consumed, which is just one bug causing another.

Comment: Why would the process output need to be read, if OP only wants to cause a timeout? For it to work properly in the end, they need to read the output for sure, but why would it be required for the process to finish or time out?